# Is IntentService an implementation of Command Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, android, android-development, mvp

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

> In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or trigger an event at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters.

And according to [professor Schmidt's text](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/CommandRevisited.pdf), a command has:

- ***Time-independent execution of application logic.*** The encapsulation of
  application logic allows to queue it and execute it at a different point in
  time.
- ***Context-independent execution of the application logic.*** The separation
  between application logic and context allows to execute the application
  in separate contexts, such as in a different thread or using a different state.
- ***Exchangeability of application logic.*** The separation between application
  logic and context allows to easier exchange the application logic.

If you encapsulate all information into an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html), the [`onHandleIntent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) works as an abstract method to the command executor, just like described at [command processor pattern](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs282/PDFs/8-Services-and-IPC-parts-7-8-and-9.pdf) text.

Thus, instead of explicitly implement the executor in order to invoke a command, you simply delegate command execution to the operating system.

So the questions are:

1. Is IntentService the framework implementation for command pattern?
2. In affirmative case, why some Android [MVP implementations](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/07/18/architecting-android-the-evolution/) explicitly implements its own, using [`ThreadExecutor`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) as consumer and [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) as commands, instead of using the one provided by the framework?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue IntentService is not a framework implementation of the command-executor design pattern, because it does not meet the requirement of the separation of application logic and application context.

The command-executor pattern is like providing a button on a remote control to replay some action(s) on-demand (dim the lights, close curtains, turn on Barry Manilow) no matter who presses it in whatever context. Command-executor is analogous to materialising a personal assistant who then does a bunch of predetermined tasks for you on-demand.

On the other hand, the use of the IntentService class is analogous to a pedestrian hailing a taxi cab or a pub patron flagging the bartender: The agent requests a service (expresses an intent), the agent enters a queue to receive the service, the agent finally receives the service. Unlike the command-executor, *this sequence requires the participation of the agent*, which itself requires that the agent be in the right kind of context to (want to) receive the service. But this is not what the command-executor pattern prescribes. Indeed, the API class overview for IntentService [in the link you provided](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) suggests that the IntentService class fits another established design pattern:

> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks 
>   from an application's main thread.  The IntentService class exists to 
>   simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics.  To use it,
>   extend  IntentService and implement `onHandleIntent(Intent)`.
>   IntentService  will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and
>   stop the service as  appropriate.

In a sense, the IntentService *could be* considered a command-executor *if only* the subject of the service could also be included in the abstraction. So for our analogies, if at any time we wished, we could invoke a command to "send my niece Suzy the birthday present I bought her" or "send me to Beijing to complete the business merger", then IntentService might be a command-executor. But when we state the comparison this way, it becomes clear IntentService could not be command-executor, because these events are *dependent on context* in the sense that they need objects or agents' participations prior to being able to run. This is not true for command-executors, which package all the necessary components for ready replay at any time.